# gitversion - increment csproj version and tag same commit

Tags: .net-core, gitversion

I am new to `gitversion` and am struggling slightly to achieve my desired affect. Up until this point, we would upgrade the `Version` tag of the `.csproj` file, commit, and then tag the commit. The result: the tag of a version is on the same commit where the version is incremented.

Then we switched to `gitversion`, with the intent to make things a bit more automatic. We now run `gitversion /updateprojectfiles` when we want to update the version. The problem with this, though, is that the version is set based on the last tag (probably due to our configuration), so the tag for the version cannot be on the commit that includes this change.  In other words, if this should now be version 0.6.0, running the aforementioned command sets it still to 0.5.0, unless we tag before we update (not ideal).

What can I do differently, to still use this command and have the tag on the same commit that upgrades the version in the `.csproj` file?

The GitVersion.yml file:

```
branches:
  master:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    tag:
    increment: Patch
  develop:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tag: alpha
    increment: Patch
  feature: {}
ignore:
  sha: []
merge-message-formats: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of executing GitVersion is to produce a version number **from Git metadata**, not the other way around. GitVersion will produce the same version number from the same commit on the same branch, regardless of when or where that commit is built, so all intermediary version numbers between your stable tags do not need to be committed to Git.

`gitversion /updateprojectfiles` is thus supposed to be executed during the build on a CI/CD server and the modified project files are to be considered build artifacts – not something that should be committed to source control.